# How can I upload a video on Instagram using Python?

Tags: python, instagram

The Instagram page does not have an option to upload videos when you open the page from a computer, I usually use Python Selenium to find a position on the screen and send text or upload/download a file, however, I cannot use Selenium on Instagram because the Instagram version for Computer does not show any button to upload a video.
I did a testing using INSTABOT to upload a photo, the testing was successful, but when I try to upload a video, INSTABOT cannot upload it.
I would like to know if someone has any script to upload videos on Instagram using python.
Thanks

Comment: you can use instapy-cli, though I can't guarantee it'll work. It's better to check the official docs

Answer (score 0):

Use this library:

https://github.com/instagrambot/instapy-cli/tree/master/examples

Here is an example of what you asked:

```
from instapy_cli import client

username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
video = 'docs/video-sample-upload.mp4'
text = 'This will be the caption of your video.' + '\r\n' + 'You can also use hashtags! #hash #tag #now'

with client(username, password) as cli:
    cli.upload(video, text)
```

Comment: I have tried it .It doesn't work.it keeps giving me error. It gives this error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extension'".If you have any solution please reply